# How to to access web service in asp.net web site whcih publish on windows azure Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service

I am building a C# web service. It works fine in Visual Studio 2013. I deployed it on IIS in a Windows Azure VM, and this also works fine. This web service is basically used for getting data such as event logs and start/stop service lists from the remote machine. I am consuming this web service in another ASP.NET web site as a Web Reference. This client web site accesses the data from the web service perfectly when debugging locally in Visual Studio.

Now I want to deploy the client web site to another VM on the same live domain which uses the web service in Windows Azure Web Apps. When I do this, it gives the following error:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:8080

Is there a way that I can access a web service which is deployed on a domain joined machine in a Windows Azure Web Apps site?

Please help me and give me any suggestions to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking (please have an English speaking friend improve your grammar if possible), but I see you posted the loopback IP address of 127.0.0.1. That should probably be replaced with the IP (or ideally, DNS name) of the service you're trying to communicate with.

Comment: I want to use a web service. This Web service is hosted out side the windows azure portal.

Please gives me any idea how can I consume this web service in Asp.net Web Site. This Asp.net web site is publish in windows azure.                                                                                                          Because when I call this web service with IP  the same error comes.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the port that you have listed is `8080`. I strongly suspect that port will be blocked by default on the VM firewall. Assuming it's a VM, you should be able to open that up in the Windows Firewall.

Alternatively, move the application to be deployed on port 80 instead, as this will be open by default.